# Angular use different index.html for route

Tags: angularjs

I'm fairly new to Angular and still figuring stuff out.
What i want to do is i have an app that uses an `index.html` and then inside it's body the `ng-view`.

Now i need to ignore that for a specific `route` `/game` in my application and use a different one. Basically i wanna do an iframe 100% in that new view but all the CSS and sidebars etc from the `index.html` file screws up the whole thing.

```
app.config(function($routeProvider){
.when('/game',{
        templateUrl: 'game.html'
    }),
.when('/home',{
        templateUrl: 'views/home.html'
    })
});
```

How should i approach this ?

Thanks

Comment: You cannot but you can check `ui-.router` that may fit better your needs

Comment: What if i use some kind of different `app-module` ?

Comment: why would css in main page mess up iframe css? No reason iframe can't be made to go full screen from inside `ng-view` using very basic position css

Comment: For your case better use stateprovider (  http://jsfiddle.net/yaprak/789Ks/1/ )

Comment: @Hemakrishnan don't see that you've made a case for switching routers although I agree that ui-router is far more robust

Comment: Would use `ui-router` if the project wasn't so deep in development with a tight schedule. CSS was messing up the page due to sidebar and header.
Anyway i worked around it with some `ng-class` and css to go full screen.